# jQuery image rotator: function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have transformed a custom image header into an image rotator by using this tutorial to build the rotator script from scratch: http://fearlessflyer.com/2012/12/how-to-create-a-jquery-image-rotator. I went step by step through the tutorial to type the code, but when I try to run, the Firebug console gives this error:

> ReferenceError: rotateImages is not defined
>
> xx = setInterval('rotateImages()', 4000);

Thinking that I might have mistyped a line of code, I copied the script from the working demo, and I received the same error.

I am running this script in a .js file:

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

    //loop through pictures
    $('.headerpic_inner').each(function(e) {
        if(e == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }

        $(this).attr('id', 'handle' + e);

    });


    //loop through tags
    $('.tabs li').each(function(e) {
        if(e == 0) {
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }

        $(this).wrapInner('<a class="title"></a>');
        $(this).append('<a><img /></a>');
        $(this).children('a').attr('href', '#handle' + e);
        y = $('#handle' + e + ' img').attr('src');
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', y);
        t = $(this).children('a').text();
        $('#handle' + e).append('<h2>' + t + '</h2>');

    });


    //change image on click
    $('.tabs li a').click(function() {

        c = $(this).attr('href');
        if($(c).hasClass('current')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            showImage($(c), 20);
            $('.tabs li').removeClass('current');
            $(this).parent().addClass('current');
            return false;
        }

    });




    //call to rotate images
    runRotateImages();
    $('#headerpic').hover(function() {
        clearTimeout(xx);
    },
    function() {
        runRotateImages();
    });





}); //end of $(document).ready function



//showImage function
function showImage(img, duration) {
    $('.headerpic_inner').removeClass('current').css({
        'opacity' : 0.0,
        'zIndex' : 2,
    });

    img.animate({opacity:1.0}, duration, function() {
        $(this).addClass('current').css({zIndex:1});

    });

}


//rotateImages function
function rotateImages() {
    var curPhoto = $('div.current');
    var nxtPhoto = curPhoto.next();
    var curTab = $('.tabs li.current');
    var nxtTab = curTab.next();

    if(nxtPhoto.length == 0) {
        nxtPhoto = $('#headerpic div:first');
        nxtTab = $('.tabs li:first-child');
    }

    curTab.removeClass('current');
    nxtTab.addClass('current');
    showImage(nxtPhoto, 300);

}

//runRotateImages function
function runRotateImages() {
    xx = setInterval('rotateImages()', 4000);
}




})(jQuery);
```

Can anyone tell me why it would say that rotateImages() is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers provided a fix but they didn't explain why your code doesn't work. I'll have a stab:

`setInterval()` can actually take a quoted argument as a string, your original code is actually syntactically correct:

```
xx = setInterval('rotateImages()', 4000);
```

So why doesn't it work? When you pass the argument with quotes, the `setInterval()` call will look in the global scope for the function `rotateImages()`. The problem is, your function `rotateImages()` is defined within a closure. Your entire code is wrapped using:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {


    });
})(jQuery);
```

The suggested fix `setInterval(rotateImages, 4000)` works because when you pass the function name without quotes and without parenthesis, `setInterval()` will first look in the local scope for the function, where it finds the function and can call it.

Comment: The other answers fixed it, but left me wondering why the same exact code worked on the tutorial demo, but not on my site where I have to wrap my code in the the $jquery function because I'm using Drupal 7. This explains it! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var xx = setInterval(rotateImages, 4000);
```

You have to setInterval like the above one.

Comment: When I tried this before, I got this error:
Error: useless setInterval call (missing quotes around argument?)

I realize that it was because I used the rotateImages() instead of rotateImages.

Works now! Thanks!

Comment: Any idea why it would show the two test pictures that I have provided and show a blank slide after?

Comment: That is a plugin fault that it does not checks whether the slider contains next image or not!

Comment: The fix was to move my tabs out of the #headerpic div. Of course, I didn't provide my HTML for you to see that.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the single quotes from around it and it should work.

Try like this :

```
xx = setInterval(rotateImages, 4000);
```